# Appending array contents to html table

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, append

First of thanks for any and all help with this.

I am attempting to loop through an array I am getting back from an Ajax call and append it to my HTML. I have attempted numerous examples and non seem to stick will with me and my project.

Here is my current Js function:

```
function OnSuccess(response) {
    console.log(response);

    $.each(response.MarketingUrls, function (index, element) {
        //$(element.UrlMaterial).find('.dets').html('<a target="_blank">Imprev Marketing Material</a>');
        $('#dets').children('a').text(element.UrlMaterial);
        console.log(element.UrlMaterial); 
    });
    $.each(response.MarketingUrls, function (index, element) {
        console.log(element.Description);
    });

}
```

Here is the HTML  I am attempting to append to:

```
<tr class="details" id="detailsSection">
            <td  colspan="5">
                <div id="dets"><a> </a></div>           
   </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: This is similar to the question you asked earlier.  So i'll repeat my statement.  You are looping, but you have not made an attempt at appending.  Why not?

Comment: Or are the commented out parts what you've tried?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/append  https://api.jquery.com/html

Comment: @Taplar I am attempting to clean up my question and include attempts. Yeah some of the commented out code are things I have tried, as well as, the current line `$('#dets').children('a').text(element.UrlMaterial);` as an attempt. Just cant seem to get this piece figured out.

Comment: @Taplar I have this working now, I actually ended up going back to one of my previous attempts, and I moved where my Ajax is getting called. Now it appends.

Comment: Good deal.  In order to increase the usefullness of this question for future readers, could you summarize your issue and what you did to solve it in an answer?